# Unable to use jquery ajax to get sound file due to cross origin access control

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5-audio

I seem to be unable to check if a audio file exists before it actions anything due to No Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

Is it possible to have this and if so, how ?

```
pText[n] = any word, for example: and, about.
```

But googles API do not hold names, so I need to check if a name is added to the text, and if so, use a different source url.

```
        // audio check
    var audioCheck = $.get('https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/' + pText[n] +'.mp3');
    console.log(audioCheck);
```

I have also tried $.ajax but without success.

This is the full script so you can see what I am doing

```
function populate(pText) {

for(var n=0; n < pText.length; n++) {

    // audio check
    var audioCheck = $.get('https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/' + pText[n] +'.mp3');
    console.log(audioCheck);
    // if(audioCheck) { link is live } else { link is 404 }


    //console.log(pText[n]);
    $('[name=p1_1]').append('<span id="s' + n + '"><audio id="a' + n + '" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/' + pText[n] +'.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>' + pText[n] + '</span> ');
    }
}
```

And help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this using the simple method of **onerror**

Here is the full code :)

```
function populate(pText) {

    var tex = '';

    for(var n=0; n < pText.length; n++) {
        //console.log(pText[n]);
        tex += '<span id="s' + n + '"><audio id="a' + n + '" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/' + pText[n] +'.mp3" onerror="mediaerro(' + n + ',&quot;' + pText[n] +'&quot;)" type=audio/mpeg"></audio>' + pText[n] + ' </span>';
    }
    $('[name=p1Text]').html(tex);
}

$(document).on("click", "span", function() {

    $(this).find('audio')[0].play();

});

mediaerro = function(id, word) {
    console.log(word);
    switch(word) {
        case "Rocko":
            $('#a' + id).attr('src', 'http://domain.com/books/book1/words/rocko.mp3');
            break;
        case "Caroline":
            $('#a' + id).attr('src', 'http://domain.com/books/book1/words/caroline.mp3');
            break;
        case "Benji":
            $('#a' + id).attr('src', 'http://domain.com/books/book1/words/benji.mp3');
            break;
    }
};
```

Using the dynamic audio id and managed to create a function based on an error, which replaces the broken link with a new one where the new recording is.  Works a treat!